# Хранятся ли значения элементов массива примитивных типов в heap?

Tags: java, массивы, стек, heap

Есть такой немного джуниорский вопрос, ответ на который мне очень интересно узнать. Как мы знаем, массивы в Java - это полноценные объекты. Также знаем, что примитивные переменные хранятся в стеке со своими адресами и значениями.

Вопрос! Когда мы создаем массив примитивных типов, сам массив хранится в heap-e, его адрес в стеке. Хранятся ли значения элементов массива в heap-е? Или в массиве хранятся адреса на значения в стеке?

Answer (score 2):

В массиве примитивных типов хранятся значения элементов; в heap-е.